# Redux thunk caller get response

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have Redux slice and thunk actions of an entity that is managed by a backend server. I have "Create" action implemented by Redux thunk. When the server gets the Create request with the entity details, it returns the new ID that the server generates. How can I get that ID in the caller component?

My action (written with Redux Toolkit):

```
export const createTodoAction = createAsyncThunk(
  "todos/CREATE",
  async (todo: Todo) => {
    const fullTodo = await createTodoApi(todo);
    return fullTodo; // Contains the ID from the server
  }
);
```

My component:

```
function CreateTodoForm() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const onFormSubmit = (form: Todo) => {
      dispatch(createTodoAction(form));

      // How can I get the ID here?
   }

   ...
}
```

My intuitive solution is to call the API directly from the component and convert the `createTodoAction` to a regular Redux action (not thunk). But all my other actions are written with Redux thunk, so it seems a little bit weird that one operation has to call the API directly from the component.

Is there any way to get the response from the thunk action in the caller component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thunks created with `createAsyncThunk` return the final dispatched action as the result of `dispatch(thunk())`.  So, you can [unwrap the result action to get the payload value](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions):

```js
function CreateTodoForm() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const onFormSubmit = async (form: Todo) => {
      const resultAction = await dispatch(createTodoAction(form));
      try {
        const payload = unwrapResult(resultAction);
        // do something with payload here
      } catch (err) {
        // call must have failed - can optionally handle error here
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting, I saw that in the docs but it never worked for me... It seems that `dispatch` returns a `function` and not a `promise` (at least the type definition in Typescript). I can't use `await` or `then` on `dispatch`...

Comment: You need to type your `dispatch` correctly. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type

Comment: I have some issue with the typing. The reducer that generated from `createSlice` defined with `AnyAction` so the `store.dispatch` has type `Dispatch<AnyAction>`. So it not accepts thunks. Similar to: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/45575

Comment: Yes, as shown in that linked docs page, you need to explicitly declare that you are using a version of `Dispatch` that accepts thunks.

Comment: @markerikson, true. But `export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch` is actually `type AppDispatch = Dispatch<AnyAction>`, which doesn't accept thunks. My slice use only `extraReducers` with the thunks handlers. How should I declare the `AppDispatch` with `Dispatch` that accepts thunks? What am I missing?...

Comment: What you're missing is that if the store has been configured correctly, the store type itself has been augmented to understand that thunks may be passed to `dispatch`.  So, when you then infer `type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch`, that type is now "smarter" than the base `Dispatch` type.

Comment: @markerikson It is my first time that I use redux toolkit. I've followed your documentation when I created the slice... I've created a small repro here: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-dispatch-type-fr6rj?file=/src/App.tsx

If you can take a look please at line 71 and tell me what I'm doing wrong, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to stop using `createStore` (which is from the basic Redux library), and switch to using [the `configureStore` API from Redux Toolkit instead](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore).  That not only sets up the thunk middleware, but has the correct type inference to make sure that `typeof store.dispatch` includes the thunk types.